# Is it possible to get map of area between two cities whose latitude and longitude are given

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I know how to get map of a place whose latitude and longitude are given, but i don't now how to **get map of area between two cities**. 
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution, you need `LatLng` of towns, for example center point:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

bounds.extend(latLngOfFirstTown);
bounds.extend(latLngOfSecondTown);

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: thanks for your help Anto. But I think this won't work when the cities are quite far apart.

Comment: It works, for example, for New York - Shangai or New York - Canberra or Shangai - Canberra. Do you have some example which doesn't work?